# Using Youtube Data API v3 with ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, youtube-api

How can I upload using ASP.net MVC 4 `async`:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

It seems like lacking of MVC example.

Comment: which version of asp.net are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASYNC file upload using mvc web api and
upload the files.

Please see below link for help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx